# Magento 2 REST API : Product Price and Custom Attribute color are not reflecting in response

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento2 [v2.4] Product integration use case. 
I am creating a **Product** using [REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/create-simple-products.html) [postman] and observed that product **price**, **color** attributes are present in Request JSON but those are missing in Response received from Magento.

```
POST http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products
        
Request:
{
  "product": {
    "id": "2007",
    "sku": "20210004",
    "name": "Iphone 4",
    "price": "400",
    "status": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "qty": 4,
        "is_in_stock": "true"
      }
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
        
Response:
{
  "id": 2007,
  "sku": "20210004",
  "name": "Iphone 4",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "extension_attributes": {
    "stock_item": {
      "item_id": 18,
      "product_id": 2007,
      "stock_id": 1,
      "qty": 4,
      "is_in_stock": true,
      "is_qty_decimal": false
    }
  },
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "options_container",
      "value": "container2"
    },
    {
      "attribute_code": "url_key",
      "value": "iphone-4"
    }
   ]
}
```

If you look at the request and response payload, you will see that *Price* and *Color* are there in request but somehow Magento did not honor those and got missed in response.

If I want to make this work, I had to re-send same payload again. Then I could see Price and Color in response.
Could you please suggest what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This is down to a bug in Magento (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13639).

At the time of writing this should be fixed in 2.4.3. For versions 2.4.2 and lower you can add the following to your payload:

`"type_id": "simple"`